# Page content fetched a second time on the client when using Server-side rendering

Tags: server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

When server-side rendering a page, the page content is fetched by the server (Node-) application and passed to the client application via the serverApp-state. On the client the page content is then fetched a second time, even though the information should already be there.

What is the reason for this redundant call?

Thank you,

Armin Hutzler

Comment: This sounds like a bug. As you describe, the state, including the page data, should be transferred to the client. Would you mind creating a ticket with a reproduction(steps), so we can follow up?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reply. I created an issue in the Repository: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/issues/6337

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer:

This seems like a bug.
@Armin has created a new github ticket for it: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/issues/6337